# My PS VITA doesnot turn On

Tags: ps-vita

I am trying to turn on PSVita but it blink icon on screen and didnot turn On. 
i charge my PSVita but unable to Turn On it.. 
Please help me... 
I tried to charge the PSVita. It show yellow light on Icon after few minute light is turned off.

Comment: This actually sounds like you've got a hardware problem if you're trying to charge it and the light isn't staying on. You should contact Sony technical support for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extract from the [official Playstation site](http://manuals.playstation.net/document/en/psvita/basic/charge.html).

> When the PS button blinks orange during charging, the battery charge is too low to turn on your system. Wait until the PS button stops blinking and lights up orange before turning on your system.

Yes, this is true even if the PS Vita is *currently charging*. Just be patient, the PS Vita will eventually wake up.